# Manually Transpiling React JSX with Babel-cli

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx, babel-cli, babel-core

How can I compile a `.jsx` file using the `npx babel-cli [inpfile].jsx --out-file [outfile].js --plugin=@[someplugin]` command. I have tried `--plugin=@plugin-transform-react-jsx` but it gives error on the very first JSX expression.

I have babel-cli, babel-core etc. packages installed.

I can use `create-react-app` and everything works fine but I want to do this manually, compiling JSX.

Also if ES6 to ES5 conversion is possible with the *same procedure*; please state it also.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe it should just be `babel`, not `babel-cli` https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#compile-files

Comment: @Jayce444 if you try to install babel, npm will tell you that it is deprecated, use babel-cli because package has been renamed. If you try compiling, it gives error that you have mistakenly typed babel, use babel-cli. I have done complete research on my end before asking on SO. Thanks for investing time btw.

Comment: Can you share your package.json as well? I need to see all your babel versions (including presets/plugins)

Comment: @tmhao2005 I don't have any package file. I don't know much about this. I've been using `create-react-app`.

Comment: Ah I see. But you should install babel things locally at your project. Try to install them and try again.

Comment: Do you know which ones should be installed? If you didn’t, I would offer a help

Comment: @tmhao2005 yes! sure, I'm here seeking help. I've tried installing babel-cli, babel-core and preset-react. but preset-react says babel-core isn't installed but it is installed. You can start explaining from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just simply install the latest babel packages (looks like you were trying to install the old ones). Here's a few steps:

- Install needed packages:

```sh
npm i -D @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

- Run your test jsx file:

```sh
npx babel path/to/yourFile.jsx --presets=@babel/preset-env,@babel/preset-react
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. Note that if the OP only wants to transpile JSX, the `@babe/present-env` seems to be unnecessary.